# How to run cursor in snowflake?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have written below cursor in SQL and working file.
But I am not able to run the same cursor on snowflake, please help.

```
DECLARE @CurrentMonth NVARCHAR(100)
DECLARE @CurrentMonth1 NVARCHAR(100)
DECLARE MYDateCURSOR CURSOR
DYNAMIC 
FOR
SELECT Collections_COE FROM [CollectionsAgeing_OTCN024_028_029]
OPEN MYDateCURSOR
FETCH LAST FROM MYDateCURSOR INTO @CurrentMonth
CLOSE MYDateCURSOR
DEALLOCATE MYDateCURSOR
--select  value from STRING_SPLIT(@CurrentMonth,'-') ;
select @CurrentMonth1=LEFT(@CurrentMonth,4)+cast(cast(RIGHT(@CurrentMonth,2) as int)-1 as varchar(2))
select Date, x1,y1,x1/y1 as DividedValue, round((x1/y1)-1,5) as Actual from(
SELECT  X.Past_Due_0 as x1,Y.Past_Due_0 as y1,X.Collections_COE as Date FROM [CollectionsAgeing_OTCN024_028_029] X
CROSS JOIN [CollectionsAgeing_OTCN024_028_029] Y
WHERE X.Collections_COE=@CurrentMonth and y.Collections_COE=@CurrentMonth1
)z
```

Comment: Hi Neeraj, you'll get a better response if you sort out the formatting of your code.  When posting or editing a question you should see some guidance on the formatting on the right hand side, or else have a look in the help section

Answer (score 2):

[Snowflake Scripting](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/developer-guide/snowflake-scripting/index.html) introduced support for cursors.

> **[Working with Cursors](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/developer-guide/snowflake-scripting/cursors.html)**
>
> You can use a cursor to iterate through query results one row at a time.
>
> ###### Introduction
>
> To use a cursor, do the following:
>
> 1. In the DECLARE section, declare the cursor. The declaration includes the query for the cursor.
> 2. Execute the OPEN command to open the cursor. This executes the query and loads the results into the cursor.
> 3. Execute the FETCH command to fetch one or more rows and process those rows.
> 4. When you are done with the results, execute the CLOSE command to close the cursor.

Answer (score 1):

Snowflake SQL does not support native SQL cursors.  I believe you'll want to leverage a Javascript UDF, UDTF, or Stored Procedure (depending on what you want your output to be).  Based on your example above, I believe a Javascript UDTF is what you need:  https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/udf-js-table-functions.html

Answer (score 0):

Snowflake SQL does not support native SQL cursors there are options which can be leveraged for your scenario. Please take a look at below links. Also please be informed that Snowflake's real processing power in terms of performance is when data is processed in bulk instead of processing data row by row.

https://community.snowflake.com/s/question/0D50Z00009f7StWSAU/i-have-written-below-cursor-in-sql-and-working-file-but-i-am-not-able-to-run-the-same-cursor-on-snowflake-please-help

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/python-connector-example.html

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/udf-js-table-functions.html

Comment: Your two answers ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61674751) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61629750)) are rather copy-paste similar, which we tend to discourage. Answers should be tailored to each question. Additionally, answers should not rely on links - they are OK if they are part of the answer, but they should not be the main part of the answer.