# Porting Oracle PL/SQL to Snowflake without JavaScript

Tags: oracle, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I may have missed it, but it looks like Snowflake only lets the user define JavaScript UDFs.  I don't dislike JavaScript *per se*, but I have a package containing PL/SQL stored procedures and a couple of functions.  I'd like to run these on Snowflake, but would rather not need to convert everything to JavaScript.

Especially because I can't do something like

```
INSERT INTO...
```

but now need to do something like

```
var sql='INSERT INTO...'
Snowflake.execute (sql);
```

Most of the PL/SQL inserts from one table based off the select from another query.  Some functions do bulk fetches. Is there an easier way?

Comment: One small correction to your post.  Snowflake does support SQL UDFs, just not SQL Stored Procedures.

Answer (score 1):

Though Snowflake SQL does not support PL/SQL or native SQL cursors but there are options which can be leveraged for your scenario. Please take a look at below links. Also please be informed that Snowflake's real processing power in terms of performance is when data is processed in bulk instead of processing data row by row.

https://community.snowflake.com/s/question/0D50Z00009f7StWSAU/i-have-written-below-cursor-in-sql-and-working-file-but-i-am-not-able-to-run-the-same-cursor-on-snowflake-please-help

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/python-connector-example.html

Comment: Your two answers ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61674751) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61629750)) are rather copy-paste similar, which we tend to discourage. Answers should be tailored to each question. Additionally, answers should not rely on links - they are OK if they are part of the answer, but they should not be the main part of the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Snowflake does not support PL/SQL, which is proprietary to Oracle. Looks like the recommended approach is to rewrite the procedures in Python and use Snowflake's Python API.

https://redpillanalytics.com/so-you-want-to-migrate-to-snowflake-part-2/
https://support.snowflake.net/s/question/0D50Z00008nRRhdSAG/i-am-migrating-oracle-plsql-code-into-snowflake-which-is-the-best-way-to-implement-this-using-java-api-or-python-api

Comment: Most articles that you see that make recommendations for rewriting in Python were before Snowflake has Javascript Stored Procedures available.  Javascript SP's are the only native Snowflake solution, while Python requires a separate execution environment.